# How to pass model as input parameter in method in Angular10?

Tags: angular, model, httpservice

```
I am having one model(login.model.ts) in my angular project like below - 

export class LoginModel{
    public uName: string;
    public uPassword: string;
}

I want to use this model as input parameter in method called 'login' in my service(authentication.service.ts) from where I am doing **POST** request. How can I do that? May be something like below.

login(LoginModel lm){
  //my post request here
}
```

And inside this login method want to use like 'lm.uName' /  'lm.uPassword'

Comment: You just need to type lm like this -> `lm : LoginModel` that's it

Comment: This is a tip about formatting the question. You should use the Code sample option in the editor for code only. The Description text should be outside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like below.

```
login(lm: LoginModel){
  //my post request here
}
```

Comment: thank you. it is working. Actually I am new in Angular and being a .net developer I passed model like that :P

Comment: okay. just get basic idea of typescript. that will help you. Above syntax is not related to angular but typescript.

Comment: thank u for your advice. I am new in typescript as well :P

Answer (score 0):

So you will have to make the parameter with the type of loginModel. So

```
login(lm: LoginModel) { 
    // lm.uname = 'abc';
    // logic here, api call
    // etc
  }
```